# My strace program gave wrong output under 64bit linux system

Tags: linux, strace, ptrace

I am building an online judge system. The key point is to trace system calls.

I choose ptrace. The subprocess will stopped because of SIGTRAP when it's going to enter one system call, then the parent process goes to read the orig_rax (orig_eax)register of subprocess to get the system call number.

When the code is running under Opensuse13.1 32bit, no problem, its output is the same as the linux command strace.

But I just test the code under Opensuse13.1 64bit, Ubuntu12.04 64bit, its output is wrong.

The demo code can be downloaded here : https://gist.github.com/kainwen/41a7bd0198099d766bda

Under 64bit linux system, you save the code `strace_ls.c`, compile it `gcc strace_ls.c`, and run it`./a.out 2>out`. The output is [here](https://gist.github.com/kainwen/3a81e265cc9e045a9bce)

So my code's output is strange.

My code and its output is below:

```c
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void judge_exe()
{
    pid_t pid ;
    int insyscall = 0 ;
    struct user context ;
    
    pid = fork() ;
 
    if (pid == 0) { //child
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME,0,NULL,NULL) ;
        execl("/usr/bin/ls","ls",NULL) ;
    }
    else {//parent
        int status ;
        ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, NULL);

        while (1) {
            wait(&status) ;
            if (WIFEXITED(status))  //normally terminated
                break;
            else if (WIFSTOPPED(status) &&  (WSTOPSIG(status)==SIGTRAP)) {
                if (!insyscall) {
                    insyscall = 1;
                    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS,pid,NULL,&context.regs);
                    fprintf(stderr,"syscall num: %d \n",context.regs.orig_rax);
                } else
                    insyscall = 0;
            }
            ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,pid,NULL,NULL);
        }
        return;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    judge_exe();
}
```

The output of the code above is (just heading lines):

```
syscall num: 59 
syscall num: 12 
syscall num: 9 
syscall num: 21 
syscall num: 2 
syscall num: 4
```

The heading lines of output of the linux command `strace ls` is:

```
execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 101 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1bab000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efff4326000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/lib64/tls/x86_64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/lib64/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff00c49b80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The number of system call sys_execve is 11, not 59 (the output of my code)

---

#### Solved

My method is right. The syscall number is different under 64bit and 32bit.

Comment: What does "output is wrong" mean? Please edit your post and include the output that you believe is wrong, and why do you think its wrong.

Comment: @PawelVeselov I think it's wrong because the linux command strace and my code gave different output for the same binary program. My code is [here](https://github.com/rorschachhb/lambdaOJ/blob/master/judge/src/judge.c), but it is tedious to compile it. This [strace code](https://github.com/DeforaOS/strace) use the same method as mine, and the output is also the same as mine, but easy to compile and run. If you run this code under opensuse13.1 64bit or Ubuntu12.04 64bit, e.g. `./strace ls`, the output is wrong at the first glance ...

Comment: You should include the output that you believe is wrong into your question (especially if stuff is tedious to compile) and explain why you think it's wrong. That's probably why you got down-voted. You also should distill the problem to the minimal runnable test-case.

Comment: Looks correct to me -- `execve` is 59 on 64-bit linux, `brk` is 12, etc.  Note that the numbers for 64-bit linux are completely different from 32-bit linux...

Comment: @ChrisDodd Oh! I know the problem! I just look the number into a 32bit syscall list....

Comment: Please move your solution ("_The syscall number is different under 64bit and 32bit._") to an answer of its own, thank you.